# LightDM returns immediately with /etc/X11/Xsession

Tags: linux, display-manager

I have an user defined Xsession in `~/.xinitrc`. Started from console via `startx` everything works fine.

Now this session should be started by LightDM. For that I created `/usr/share/xsessions/xsession.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xsession
Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

But if I select "Xsession" as session in LightDM and log in LightDM returns immediately to login screen without displaying my user defined Xsession. What have I forgot?

Comment: `Xsession` in /usr/hare/xsessions points to a file which does **not** start a desktop. If you look at the other 'desktop` files in the same directory you will see that they point to scripts which **do** start the desktop environment.

Comment: `Xsession` itself does not but it includes files from home directory which do.

Answer (score -1):

Against [common literature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77191/how-can-i-use-lightdm-for-user-defined-sessions) `Xsession` does **not** load `~/.xinitrc`. Instead it uses `~/.xsession`. Copy or link the files each other.